# mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener NPE

Tags: java, android, android-listview

This is onCreate, and it gives NPE on mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(this)
I just want to create list menu with Country Icons and text like: Russian, English, Italian. WHen user clicks it, it must change Locale language of App. 
I thought to use DrawerNavigation instead add all different languages to OverFlowMenu.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(activity_main);

            /**
             *
             *
             *
             *
             */

            mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

            // load slide menu items
            navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(nav_drawer_items);

            // nav drawer icons from resources
            navMenuIcons = getResources()
                    .obtainTypedArray(nav_drawer_icons);

            mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

            mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(list_slidermenu);

            navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<>();

            // adding nav drawer items to array
            // English language
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
            // Russian language
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
            // Italian language
            navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));


            // Recycle the typed array
            navMenuIcons.recycle();

            mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

            // setting the nav drawer list adapter
            adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                    navDrawerItems);
            mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

            // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

            mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                    R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                    R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                    R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
            ) {
                public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                    // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }

                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                    // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            };
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

            /*if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                // on first time display view for first nav item
                displayView(0);
            }*/
            /**
             *
             *
             *
             *
             */


            storyButtonMainBody = (Button) findViewById(storyButton);
            storyButtonMainBody.setOnClickListener(this);

            specSectButton = (Button) findViewById(specSectionButtonId);
            specSectButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            webRegistryButton = (Button) findViewById(e_registryId);
            webRegistryButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            feedBackButton = (Button) findViewById(feedback);
            feedBackButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            findUsButton = (Button) findViewById(findus);
            findUsButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            communicationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_show_comunications);
            communicationButton.setOnClickListener(this);
            makeActionOverflowMenuShown();
        }

        /*private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
                OnItemClickListener {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {
                // display view for selected nav drawer item
                displayView(position);
            }
        }*/

        /* *
         * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
         */
        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
            boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
            menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
            return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        }


        /**
         * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
         */
        private void displayView(int position) {
            // update the main content by replacing fragments
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    Locale locale = new Locale("en");
                    Locale.setDefault(locale);
                    Configuration config = new Configuration();
                    config.locale = locale;
                    getBaseContext()
                            .getResources()
                            .updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext()
                                    .getResources()
                                    .getDisplayMetrics());
                    restartActivity();
                    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.locale_lang, LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Locale locale2 = new Locale("ru");
                    Locale.setDefault(locale2);
                    Configuration config2 = new Configuration();
                    config2.locale = locale2;
                    getBaseContext()
                            .getResources()
                            .updateConfiguration(config2, getBaseContext()
                                    .getResources()
                                    .getDisplayMetrics());
                    restartActivity();
                    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.locale_lang, LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Locale locale3 = new Locale("it");
                    Locale.setDefault(locale3);
                    Configuration config3 = new Configuration();
                    config3.locale = locale3;
                    getBaseContext()
                            .getResources()
                            .updateConfiguration(config3, getBaseContext()
                                    .getResources()
                                    .getDisplayMetrics());
                    restartActivity();
                    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.locale_lang, LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            }

            if (fragment != null) {

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

                // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
                mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
                mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
                setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            } else {
                // error in creating fragment
                Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Post the full code of your onCreate() method (the mDrawerList variable is null)

Comment: Check line number 116 of your main activity that is causing issue.

Comment: Yes, but its line with //some comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this line

```
mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(list_slidermenu);
```

you are looking for a view (whose *id* is stored in `list_slidermenu`) which does not exist in the layout file identified by the variable `activity_main`

Check how you assign `activity_main` and `list_slidermenu`, they must be valid android R identifier (*like R.id.drawer_layout*); if not, here's the problem. After that, open the layout file an check the item identified by the `list_slidermenu`.

Comment: Hm... I've found this problem, but another problem is:
I want to add navigationdrawer to my exist project without changen contentview(activity_main);

Comment: @ArnoldMrARNOLDCharyyev this is completely unrelated to your original question (you asked about an NPE exception).
If you resolved THIS issue, mark this question and then, only if it's really necessary, open a new specific question

Comment: Understood. Seems that this problem fixed, but after that problem I've got new NPE on  mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

Comment: @ArnoldMrARNOLDCharyyev That's the same type of error, just go back and check as you did for the mDrawerList

Comment: same problem as before :(

Comment: @ArnoldMrARNOLDCharyyev I think that you actually have no idea of what you are doing. I suggest you to start from some tutorial about Android fundamentals